# Can I declare a Scanner in a public class?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm a learner (very basic for now). I ask question when I don't find a legit answer.

Can I declare scanner in public class so I don't need to declare in every function I use?

```
public class  name
{
   //can i declare scanner here? and how?
   public static int xxx2(int kk)
   {
     Scanner kb=new Scanner( System.in);
     //code
     return kk;
    }

    public static int xxx1(int kk)
    {
        Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
        //code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can just keep the `Scanner` as a record. Since you're using `System.in`, you can just initialize it inline, and don't have to worry about closing it:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Methods that can use myScanner
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can initialize variable/objects in class level also.
But the executable code should be in methods only such as any expression

```
public class MyClass{
  //this is allowed in class
  private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


  public void myScannerGet(){
     String s = scanner.readLine();

     //this must be inside method
     System.out.println(s);
  }

}
```